# Powershell Script runs independently but gives 'method invocation failed' error when run as an executable

Tags: windows, powershell, go

The following is my powershell script snippet to fetch all the installed applications:

```
$tPatchObject = @() #initialize array

#invoking the native powershell(32 bit/64 bit)
$tPatchObject =  &"$env:systemroot\sysnative\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NonInteractive -NoProfile -Command {Get-Childitem "HKLM://SOFTWARE//Microsoft//Windows//CurrentVersion//Uninstall//*" | Get-ItemProperty | Sort-Object DisplayName -Unique;};

#appending applications from a different path to same array
$tPatchObject += &"$env:systemroot\sysnative\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NonInteractive -NoProfile -Command {Get-Childitem "HKLM://SOFTWARE//Wow6432Node//Microsoft//Windows//CurrentVersion//Uninstall//*" | Get-ItemProperty | Sort-Object DisplayName -Unique}
```

When being tested on a Windows server 2008 R2 system, it gives proper output if executed directly from the powershell. But the same script when executed as part of an executable compiled in Golang gives error

> Method Invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSObject] doesn't contain a method named 'op_Addition'.

Facing this issue only on a Windows server 2008 system. My assumption is the problem occurring because of the invocation  of`&"powershell.exe"`

Answer (score 1):

try this, [LookPath](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#LookPath)

```golang
cmd := `Get-Childitem "HKLM://SOFTWARE//Microsoft//...`

ps, _ := exec.LookPath("powershell.exe")
args := append([]string{"-NoProfile", "-NonInteractive", cmd})

out, _ := exec.Command(ps, args...).Output()
```

Comment: This works but I still don't understand why invoking it from the Go source code works but not from the powershell.